# JQuery frontend with Java and C# backends: design choices

Tags: c#, java, jquery

I have to build a multibrowser web app which should be able to be installed in both Windows and Linux servers.

I've thought of using a single client-side frontend built with JQuery, and two different backends, built with java and c# respectively. The client then would use ajax calls with json to communicate with MVC frameworks on the server (ASP.net MVC for the C# version and Struts for the java one).

Is it wise? Is it viable? What other choices do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That approach makes sense - The main challenge I see would be making the interfaces exactly the same for both java and .net - little issues like not having aspx in any of the urls.

You'll also need to be doing more of the work manually than you otherwise would - for example I've found that integrating the asp.net scriptservice stuff with jquery requires a few workarounds that wouldn't be an option if you need the front end to work with both platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with C# if you have a perfectly fine cross-platform solution with Java that you can install on both windows and linux?

Comment: Political and commercial reasons. We have customers that require a .NET solution.

Comment: aaw.. too bad. Is it possible to run a java servlet container on IKVM ( http://www.ikvm.net/ ), aka "java for .NET"?

Comment: Don't think that option would be palatable to our customers. Too risky I think. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Regarding .NET version - your backend's only function is json communication? Then WCF services would be better choice I think.

Comment: Since I won't need to talk to any other server, do I really need WCF? Wouldn't page methods be enough?

Comment: Page methods are OK. But if only function of the server side is expose of services (in json format or other) and not rendering of UI, then WCF services would be a cleaner and more maintainable solution.